# Opening a link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, tabs, anchor

I've created a website for a project I'm doing.
In the content of the website there are some links for external web pages that can be visited.
In the mean time when the user clicks on one of the links he'll be taken to the specified link and he will not be on the current page anymore.
What I wanted to do is have the specified website in the link clicked appear in a new tab when the user clicks on the link. This way the user stays on the current page he's one and also can view the other page on the new tab.

I've looked on the internet and found this which seemed to be useful:

```
function externalLinks()
{
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++)
  {
      var anchor = anchors[i];
      if(anchor.getAttribute("href"))
        anchor.target = "_blank";
  }
}
window.onload = externalLinks;
```

The problem I'm facing is that the navbar of my website contains anchor tags. So now if the user clicks on the links on the navbar it will open a new tab. I want this to happen ONLY if the user clicks on a link in the content of my website. So if the user clicks on a link in the navbar it shouldn't open a new tab and should just take him to the specified destination.

I've tried adding a class to all the links in the content and use getElementByClassName but it still didn't work

Anyone can help me with this

Comment: While it probably seems like a good idea, you shouldn't really be forcing such decision on your visitor - see: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-usability/new-browser-windows.shtml

Answer (score 31, accepted):

---

You can just use HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="YourAmazingURL">Click here for Amazing URL</a>
```

Another Example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

This takes advantage of the target attribute.

More information on the target attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
Also: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

EDIT:

For XHTML, just do this:

```
<a href="YourAmazingURL" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Click here for Amazing URL</a>
```

Or, again:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Google</a>
```

---

Comment: The problem is that I'm only required to use XHTML, and when validating the page it says target is not an attribute

Comment: Thank you. I also found a way using jQuery to do it, but this way is also nice to know :-).

Answer (score 2):

Are you required to use javascript for this?

If not you could just add the attribute directly to the a tag in the HTML.

For example: `<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a>`

That would probably be an easier way for you to do it if javascript is not required.

Comment: The problem is that I'm only required to use XHTML, and when validating the page it says target is not an attribute

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rely on JavaScript:

Basically you just need to change your `if`-condition (to check whether the anchor link points to an external location or not).

So, instead of `if(anchor.getAttribute("href"))`, use `if(anchor.getAttribute("href") && anchor.hostname!==location.hostname)`.

With a bit of code clean up, your function should look as follows:

```
function externalLinks() {
  for(var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0;a < c.length;a++) {
    var b = c[a];
    b.getAttribute("href") && b.hostname !== location.hostname && (b.target = "_blank")
  }
}
;
externalLinks();
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please provide any comments as for the downvote? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you want to use `document.getElementById("theidgoeshere");`

To do this, set the id attribute in your link like so:

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="theidgoeshere">Google</a>
```

Then in your javascript

```
  var anchor = document.getElementById("theidgoeshere");
  if(anchor.getAttribute("href"))
      anchor.target = "_blank";
```

Also note you might want to do without the javascript. Just put `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag.