# Open external links in a new tab without jQuery

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

What's the best way to open all external links (URLs that don't match the current domain) in a new tab using JavaScript, without using jQuery?

Here's the jQuery I'm current using:

```
// Open external links in new tab
$('a[href^=http]').click(function () {
    var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
    if (!a.test(this.href)) {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pure JS:

```
function externalLinks() {
  for(var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0;a < c.length;a++) {
    var b = c[a];
    b.getAttribute("href") && b.hostname !== location.hostname && (b.target = "_blank")
  }
}
;
externalLinks();
```

Answer (score 3):

The **links** property returns a collection of all `<area>` and `<a>` elements in a document with a value for the href attribute.

```
   var links = document.links;
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      if (links[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
        links[i].target = '_blank';
      } 
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links

Answer (score 1):

Add a target="_blank" to the  tag. You could do that in the pre-processor (e.g. PHP) or in a JS during the onload event.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $("a[href^=http]").each(function(){
          if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
             $(this).attr({
                target: "_blank",
                title: "Opens in a new window"
             });
          }
       })
```

This script should work for you.

UPDATE : try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/GuT2y/

JS version

```
    var externalLinks = function(){
      var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      var length = anchors.length;
      for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
        var href = anchor[i].href;
        if(href.indexOf('http://sample.com/') || href.indexOf('http://www.sample.com/')){
          return;
        }
        else{
          anchor[i].target='_blank';
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Does that not use jQuery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function?

Comment: It used and add the target="_blank", then user click on it goes to the link as new tab/window

Comment: Like I say, does your solution not use jQuery's .each() function? My question specified no use of jQuery.

Comment: Just replace the each with click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273890/opening-a-link-in-a-new-tab try this, No worries to giving me negative score.

Comment: Already seen that answer and it wasn't a non-jQuery equivalent of my jQuery script.

Answer (score 0):

**Open All External Links In New Tab Using Javascript**

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href && !links[i].href.startsWith(window.location.origin)) {
      links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        openInNewTab(this.href);
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

https://vipcodemaster.blogspot.com/2024/03/open-all-external-links-in-new-tab.html