# Open Asp.net MVC View page in a Tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

how can i open an asp.net MVC view page in new tab. I have a left panel from where you will redirect to new page and i need to open that page in new tab of existing project not in new window.And also from ExtJS Sencha grid cell click.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the anchor attribute target http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp what you are looking for? If yes then look here [Opening a link in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273890/opening-a-link-in-a-new-tab) for the details how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to this in a standard way.

Opening pages in new tab or new window, is a browser configurable option, not a programmable manner. So, you haven't any control over it.

However, opening new pages(whether in new tabs or new pages) is achieved in client side by this javascript line:

```
window.open();
```

Now, you have two ways in front:

1) You just want to open a new tab/page and request a view. Just set the url in the `open()` method:

```
window.open('@Url.Action(...)');
```

2) You send some data to controller and want to show the results in new tab/page.

First, send an ajax or ordinary post request to the controller and retrieve results in the same view.

Then, open a new tab/page and put that result to it:

```
var w = window.open();
$(w.document.body).html(content.responseText);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but in view page document.ready() function is not working where i have lot of functions.so is there any another approach without ajax post.

Comment: @user2682162 - Indeed there is, but I don't remember any... However, the idea is what I told you, and you can try to add your own details to that approach...